# Vue: how to display multiple global router-view

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to set up multiple router-view to show login modal and i don't want to use nested routes because this modal should be reachable from any ware I'm my app and it should not change currently viewed component. 
How to do that?

**app.vue**

````
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app color="white" height="auto">
      <div style="width:100%" class="d-flex d-md-block">
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="9" sm="10" md="12" class=" pa-0 order-md-1 order-2">
            <AppHeader />
          </v-col>
          <v-col
            cols="3"
            sm="2"
            md="12"
            class="pa-0 order-md-2 order-1 d-flex align-center"
          >
            <Menu />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </div>
    </v-app-bar>
    <router-view class="content__holder" />
    <router-view name="modal" />
    <MpFooter />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import AppHeader from "./components/AppHeader";
import Menu from "./components/menu.vue";
import MpFooter from "./components/MpFooter";

export default {
  name: "App",

  components: {
    Menu,
    AppHeader,
    MpFooter,
  },
  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>```
````

Answer (score 0):

If it should be accessible from anywhere in the app you might consider using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/). This way you can have one `<Modal />` instance in your app.vue and manipulate the modal-state from anywhere through Vuex

Comment: yup thats good idea but i need to access not only by clicking but also by http adress (somesite.com/login)

Comment: call the vuex-action to open the modal on `mounted()` in /login if you want to instantly display the modal when entering the page